# Why is ASP.NET Core MVC Identity authentication resetting with IIS Cache-Control?

Tags: iis, http-headers, asp.net-identity, cache-control

I am using the standard Identity authentication set-up with ASP.NET core MVC. It has been working fine for a long time, but I recently added Cache-Control on the production IIS server. The app is intranet-only and updated regularly, so it was getting to be a major hassle needing to clear everyone's cache every time the app was updated.

The setting I changed is was adding

```
Cache-Control: max-age=30
```

to the Http response header.

After making this change, the Identity authentication will randomly "reset" itself. For example, a user will log in successfully; they will then navigate to a page which is protected by Identity authentication. After doing so, the user is redirected back to the login page. This can repeat an arbitrary number of times before the user is finally able to make it to the desired destination page.

The worst part is, I cannot replicate the issue in any repeatable manner. I have witnessed it multiple times, but it doesn't happen 9 times out of 10 and I can't see any reason why it happens to begin with.

Does anyone know how Cache-control affects Identity authentication?

Answer (score 0):

For cache issue, you could use iis HTTP header keep alive option.

you could follow the below steps:

1) Open IIS Manager and select the site from the connection pane.

2)Double-click on the HTTP Response Headers

[image]

3)Click Set Common Headers… from the action pane:

[image]

4)Check the Enable HTTP keep-alive checkbox, Check the box to expire Web content and set your time.

[image]

**the main reason behind to use the keep-alive connection header to keep our HTTP requests open. This will avoid the need to repeatedly close and open a new connection.**

or

you could use application pool recycling, iis output cache setti9ng.

1)From IIS, select the website.

2)Open “Output Caching” feature.

3)Click “Add…” from the Actions panel.

4)Specify an extension, Check “User-mode caching” and “Kernel-mode caching” and select the “Prevent all caching” options under each section.

[image]

5)Click OK.

6)now select Edit Feature Settings from the action pane in output cache window.

7) Uncheck Enable cache and Enable kernel cache.

[image]

8)Restart the website.

Comment: After trying both of these options, Chrome ignores both and continues to cache files. Unfortunately, the only cache configuration I have tried so far that has successfully made chrome behave properly is the Cache-Control max-age header

Comment: this common HTTP response header is cache control mode attribute. you could refer this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache) for more detail. you just need to check the Http keep-alive which helps you to open the connection. [Configure IIS Output Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-performance-settings/configure-iis-7-output-caching) and [HTTP Keep-Alive](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mscom/2006/08/08/keeping-the-connections-open-http-keep-alives/)

Comment: @dan Is there any proxy server between client and server?